# Problema al utilizar la implentacion AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, programación-móvil

tengo un problema al usar la implementación OnItemSelectedListener, todo va bien pero al momento de agregar el escucha al Spinner me tira error al correr la aplicación y se detiene el programa, pero al comentar esa linea todo regresa a la normalidad

```
package com.pro.kevin.conversionlme;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener , AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    Button btnConvertir;
    Spinner spinner;
    Spinner spinner2;

    ArrayAdapter<String> items;
    ArrayAdapter<String> decimal;
    ArrayAdapter<String> hexadecimal;

    String elementos[] = new String[]{"SELECCIONE","DECIMAL","BINARIO","HEXADECIMAL","OCTAL"};
    String elementosDecimal[] = new String[]{"BINARIO","HEXADECIMAL","OCTAL"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

        btnConvertir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConvertir);
        spinner  = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        items = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, elementos);
        decimal = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, elementosDecimal);
        spinner.setAdapter(items);

        spinner.setOnItemClickListener((AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) this);// Al agregarselo al spinner me tira el error en la app
        spinner2.setOnItemClickListener((AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) this);//igual aqui
        btnConvertir.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnConvertir:

            break;

            default:
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        switch (parent.getId()){
            case R.id.spinner:
                int seleccionado = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                if(seleccionado == 1){
                    //spinner2.setAdapter(decimal);
                }
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

Comment: ¿puedes poner que error te da?

Comment: Quise decir que me salia un mensaje que dice "lamentablemente la aplicacion se detuvo", solo ese problema es el que tengo, pero error en el android studio no me tira.

Comment: ¿Te has dado cuenta que tienes el spinner2 vacio?  faltaria spinner2.setAdapter(decimal ); Si no es eso comenta. Yo pondria los listeners como objetos en lugar de implementarlos en la clase

Comment: "lamentablemente la aplicacion se detuvo" tiene infinidad de causas, si no agregas el mensaje desplegado en LogCat es muy abierta esta pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas implementando `OnItemSelectedListener`  debe realizarse de esta forma:

```
 import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
...
...
   public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener ,  OnItemSelectedListener {
```

o también:

```
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
...
...
   public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
```

Definir el listener de esta forma:

```
//spinner.setOnItemClickListener((AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) this);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

de esta forma puedes llamar el método:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    switch (parent.getId()){
        case R.id.spinner:
            int seleccionado = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
            if(seleccionado == 1){
                //spinner2.setAdapter(decimal);
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

---

Te comento que el mensaje:

> "lamentablemente la aplicación se detuvo"

es un mensaje muy genérico, debes revisar específicamente en el `LogCat`.

Revisa que los Spinner en verdad se encuentran dentro del Layout `activity_principal.xml`

```
spinner  = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, mi problema era  lo que mencionaste primeramente

Comment: Soy nuevo programando para android, soy programador de java pero intento tener mayor conocimiento de aplicaciones android.